# oophp, method and property naming

Tags: php, oop, naming-conventions

In php, is there any difference between using

```
$myClass::method()
```

and

```
$myClass->method()
```

What's the reason for the change? (I believe `->` has been around longer.)

I could see a point of using `::` for methods and `->` for properties or vice versa.

Comment: See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4361598/50079

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`::` is the scope resolution operator, used for accessing `static` members of classes.

`->` is the member operator, used for access members of objects.

Here's an example:

```
class Car {
   public $mileage, $current_speed, $make, $model, $year;
   public function getCarInformation() {
      $output = 'Mileage: ' . $this->mileage;
      $output = 'Speed: ' . $this->current_speed;
      $output = 'Make: ' . $this->make;
      $output = 'Model: ' . $this->model;
      $output = 'Year: ' . $this->year;
      return $output; 
   }
}

class CarFactory {

    private static $numberOfCars = 0;

    public static function carCount() {
       return self::$numberOfCars;    
    }

    public static function createCar() {
       self::$numberOfCars++; 
       return new Car();
    }

}    

echo CarFactory::carCount(); //0

$car = CarFactory::createCar();

echo CarFactory::carCount(); //1

$car->year = 2010;
$car->mileage = 0;
$car->model = "Corvette";
$car->make = "Chevrolet";

echo $car->getCarInformation();
```

Comment: PHP calls it a Paamayim Nekudotayim which is so much more natural =)

Comment: Ah, thanks. Now, a good reason to bother with static classes?

Comment: @user247245: The `static` keyword is necessary for class variables only. For methods you can skip both `static` and `public`, as they change semantics only minusculy. Static classes per se make mostly sense for grouping methods (= poor mans namespace).

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
class testClass {
    var $test = 'test';
    
    function method() {
        echo $this->test;
    }
}

$test = new testClass();

$test->method();
testClass::method();
```

The output will be something like:

> test
>
> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in ... on line 7

This is because `::` makes a static call to a class while `->` is used to call methods or properties on a specific instance of a class.

Incidentally, I don't believe you can do `$test::method()` because PHP will give you a parse error like this:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM in ... on line 14

Comment: Actually `$this::method();` works since PHP5.3. (Not relevant for most shared hosting servers.)

Comment: @mario Thanks for the tip. I tried this on ideone.com and that's why I got the error.

Answer (score 0):

`::` is also used within a class/object to call its parent, e.g.:

```
parent::__constructor();
```

Also if it's called from within an object (so not statically).